# Why datatype of psobject element is being lost?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to create resources such as volumes and volcoll on storage array and then after all operation is over they will be deleted . The setup creation will be done in queue order and deletion will be happening in stack order.

Below is my code

```
function Setup-ArrayResource
{
    $Array = [pscustomobject]@{
            Array = "ArrayV4"
            UserName = "admin"
            Password ="Password"

    }

    $Resources = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

    $volumes = @([pscustomobject]@{Name ="Vol1"; size = 100gb },
                 [pscustomobject]@{Name ="Vol2"; size = 200gb }
                 )


    $Resources.Add($volumes) | out-null  


    return [pscustomobject] @{
        Array= $Array
        Resources = $Resources
    }

}

function TearDown-Resources
{
    param(
        $Setup
    )

    $Array = $Setup.Array
    $Resources = $Setup.Resources

    #$Resources

    $REsources.Reverse()

    foreach($r in $Resources)
    {
        "Deleting $R"
    }
}

$SetupObj = Setup-ArrayResource

TearDown-Resources -Setup $SetupObj
```

The result is expected as below

```
Deleting {Name =vol2 size = 214748364800 }
Deleting {Name =vol1 size = 107374182400}
```

But nothing is getting displayed.

It simply displayed as `Deleting`

when i debug it, the ResourceQueue collection is no more collections.Arraylist. It is considered as psobject. Seems the datatype of ResourceQueue is getting lost when it is getting assigned to Setupobject.

Is this the designed behavior? If so How to get the resourcequeue and Groupconfig from Setup-Arrayresources without losing it's datatype?

Comment: `$Resources.Add($volumes) | out-null` -> `$Resources.AddRange($volumes)`

Comment: @PetSerAl How come? Instead of adding array of objects into  collection , if one by one object added into collection ,it works. Can you add your answer and explain?

Comment: I am not sure what need to be explained, but can you answer this: you adding only one element into `$Resources`, how come you are expecting to see two `Deleting` lines?

Comment: @PetSerAl Oh... what a simple mistake i made. Sorry